How to get the vectorDB by chunk safely with Chroma.from_documents function?
When I use langchain and langchain_Chroma to create vectorDB for a long text, it just keeps running forever.
My text splitter setting is
text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=200)

And I have 2666 splits in total when I use the following to generate the splits.
docs = text_splitter.create_documents([text1, text2, text3])
splits = text_splitter.split_documents(docs)
print(f"{len(splits)}")
# 2666

Then I use Azure text-embedding-ada-002 to generate the vectorDB like
chroma_db = Chroma.from_documents(documents=splits_tmp, embedding=embed_model, persist_directory='./')

I experimented with changing the number of splits and got the following statistics
10 splits      6.5 seconds
20 splits      2.5 seconds
30 splits      2.9 seconds
50 splits      6.8 seconds
100 splits     11.7 seconds
200 splits     42.3 seconds

I wonder, even if I cannot generate the vectorDB for these 2666 splits all at once, could I do it part by part and then merge them together?
Or is there any built-in parameter in Chroma.from_documents that can either show the progress or do it by chunk so it won't get dead.

There is an Async API. Also, this is something worth experimenting with.
